# If $f: A\rightarrow A $ is one-to-one, why should its range have cardinality |A|?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am reading a proof of the following proposition: for a finite set $A, f: A\rightarrow A $ is a bijection if there is an inverse function $g : A\rightarrow A$ such that $\forall x \in A  \ g(f(x))=x$. When showing that $f$ is onto after it has showed that $f$ is one-to-one, the proof mentions how the fact that $f$ is one-to-one means the cardinality of its range is $|A|$. I do not understand why this is the case from the mere fact that $f$ is one-to-one. Using the definition of one-to-one, I don't see anything saying that $f$ must map every single element of $A$ onto its range- only that if 2 elements of its domain are mapped to the same element in its range, these elements are equivalent. Did the proof commit a logical error here, or is there something I'm missing? Why must the cardinality of $f$'s range here be $|A|$?

Comment: $f$ is a bijection from $A$ onto its range.

Comment: @geetha290krm I thought that $f$ is a bijection from $A$ onto its range is what we are supposed to be proving- using only the fact that $f$ is one-to-one, how can we show this? The mere fact that $f$ is one-to-one doesn't show how $f$ is a bijection, right?

Comment: Recall the definition of the range of $f$.

Comment: The word "range" should never be used in mathematics because people use it to mean two related, but different, concepts, so the potential for confusion is high. Some people use it to mean the "image" of the function: the set of all $f(a)$ as $a$ ranges over the elements of the domain; that is how it should be interpreted in this problem. Some people use it to mean the "codomain" of the function: the set of all possible outputs of the function: the set $A$ in this case, since the function is declared to go from $A$ (the domain) to $A$ (the codomain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what injective means. An injective function is one in which $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$. Note that this is equality, not equivalence.

Consider the set $S=\{(a,f(a))\}$. The cardinality of $S$ is the same as the cardinality of $A$ because each $a\in A$ appears once as the first element in a pair in $S$. Since the range of $f$ is contained in the second elements of the pairs in $S$ we get that $\lvert f(A)\rvert\le\vert S\rvert=\lvert A\rvert$.

Since $f$ is injective, each of the elements of $A$ get mapped to a unique element of $f(A)$ so there are at least as many elements of f(A) as there are of $A$ so $\lvert f(A)\rvert\ge\lvert A\rvert$.

Therefore, $\lvert A\rvert =\lvert f(A)\rvert$

Comment: Why must a one-to-one function map each of the elements of $A$ based off of the definition you provided? It seems that it is only the case that *if* $f$ does map 2 elements which have the same value, these elements are equal- but $f$ doesn't have to map all elements of $A$ to be considered one-to-one. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Shmuel You are missing the definition of a function. A function must map each of the values of the domain to a unique element of the codomain. That means each element of the domain gets mapped to only one value. The one-to-one property makes it so each element of $A$ gets mapped to a different value.

Answer (score 0):

Let an injective $f:A\to A$. Set $I:=\{x\in A|f(x)=x\}$. Then $A=I\cup (A\setminus I)$ and $f(A)=f(I)\cup f(A\setminus I)=I\cup f(A\setminus I)$, for obviously $f(I)=I$. It is enough to show that $f(A\setminus I)=A\setminus I$, because then $f(A)=A$, so $f$ is surjective, hence it is bijective.

Let $y\in f(A\setminus I)$; then there exists $x\in A\setminus I$ such that $y=f(x)$ and $y\neq x$, otherwise $x=y=f(x)$, i.e. $x\in I$, which is false. Furthermore $f(y)\neq y$, because, if not, we would have $y=f(x)=f(y)$ -false, because $f$ is injective. Thus $y\in A\setminus I$, so $f(A\setminus I)=A\subseteq I$ (1).

Let $x\in A\setminus I$; then $f(x)\neq x$, so $x\in f(A\setminus I)$, for $x\notin f(I)$. Thus $A\setminus I\subseteq f(A\setminus I)$ (2).

From (1), (2) we get the desired equality.

Answer (score -1):

Since $\,f:A\to A\,$ is a one-to-one function, it follows that $\,f:A\to\mathrm{range}(f)\,$ is a one-to-one function too.

Moreover, by definition, $\,\mathrm{range}(f)\,$ is the set $\big\{y\;\big|\;y=f(x)\;,\;x\in A\big\}\,,$ consequently, for any $\,y\in\mathrm{range}(f)$, there exists $\,x\in A\,$ such that $\,f(x)=y\,,\,$ but it means that the function $\,f:A\to\mathrm{range}(f)\,$ is onto.

Hence, $\,f:A\to\mathrm{range}(f)\,$ is a bijection because it is one-to-one and onto.

Since  $\,f:A\to\mathrm{range}(f)\,$ is a bijection, the sets $\,A\,$ and $\,\mathrm{range}(f)\,$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: Why have you downvoted my answer? Could you tell me the reason, please?